# what will happen after the Kafka consumer reads the whole partion?

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I do have a .Net code that I'm using in a windows service that has the process of initializing a consumer object and consuming the Kafka.

```
var config = new ProducerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "host1:9092,host2:9092,...",
    ClientId = ...,
    ...
};


ConsumerBuilder<byte[], byte[]> c = new ConsumerBuilder<byte[], byte[]>(config ).SetErrorHandler(_Consumer_OnError);

consumer = c.Build();

consumer.Subscribe(topics);

while (!canceled)
{
      var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);
      //handle consumed message.
      ...
}
```

I want to know that what will happen after all the messages are consumed from the partition.
FYI: There are 3 partitions and 4 nodes for consuming the information.

Answer (score 0):

From [confluent-kafka-dotnet](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/2b54dd2ab07f6eaa886d88c57143838627b2512f/src/Confluent.Kafka/IConsumer.cs#L57), `ConsumeResult<T1, T2> Consume(CancellationToken ct)` method will:

> Poll for new messages/events. Blocks
> until a consume result is available or the
> operation has been cancelled.

This means calling `Consume()` will never really stop trying to consume messages from the partition (unless something crashes or you cancel the op). So if you have two events in a partition, the third call on `Consume()` will just block until a new message is written to the partition.

Under the hood during the `Consume` method, Kafka client keeps making calls to the broker to check whether new events are written to the partition.